# Convert seconds(float) into mm:ss:ms in php

Tags: php, time

I have the below php function which takes a time argument in seconds from a database. The seconds are of type float(6,1) in the database. I then pass that value to the function below. The problem i have is if i have 1655.5 seconds i can get the hour, minutes and seconds. But how do i get the milliseconds that remain.

ie 1655.5 = 27m:35s.5ms

Thanks for any help in advance.

```
<?php
    function convertTo($init)
    {
          $hours = ($init / 3600);
          $minutes = (($init / 60) % 60);
          $seconds = $init % 60;

            if($minutes < 10)
            {
                $minutes = "0".$minutes;
            }

            if($seconds < 10)
            {
                $seconds = "0".$seconds;
            }

          $milli = /* code to ret the remaining milliseconds */   
          $stageTime = "$minutes:$seconds.$milli";
          return $stageTime;
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly slightly counter-intuitively, the easiest way would be to extract the milliseconds as the first step.

Simply [`floor()`](http://php.net/floor) the initial value, and subtract the result from the input. This will give you just the right-hand side of the decimal point, you can then multiply this by 1000 to give you the number of milliseconds - which you should then cast to an integer to ensure the resulting string is sensible.

```
function convertTo($init)
{
      $secs = floor($init);
      $milli = (int) (($init - $secs) * 1000);

      $hours = ($secs / 3600);
      $minutes = (($secs / 60) % 60);
      $seconds = $secs % 60;
      // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I have updated this function with Leading Zero. Now time will be shown like 00:00:00. I am using this one in my google analytics project it's working perfectly. I hope this may help someone else.

```
<?php
function convertTo($init)
{
    $init  = number_format($init, 2);
    $secs  = floor($init);
    $milli = (int) (($init - $secs) * 1000);
    $milli = str_pad($milli, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    ;
    $hours   = ($secs / 3600);
    $minutes = (($secs / 60) % 60);
    $minutes = str_pad($minutes, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $seconds = $secs % 60;
    $seconds = str_pad($seconds, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    if ($hours > 1) {
        $hours = str_pad($hours, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    } else {
        $hours = '00';
    }
    $Time = "$hours:$minutes:$seconds";
    return $Time;
}

?>
```